# Integrate lua with visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, lua

In the company where I am right now we use Lua for some smaller macros in our software, the software is programmed in Object Pascal. We have made our own Lua Functions we often use when developing macros.

Is there any possibility to integrate our own Lua Functions in Visual Studio Code ?

We would like to use Visual Studio Code to develop the Lua Scripts for our macros, it lightweight, easy to use and has plenty of extensions.

Answer (score 0):

There are some extensions in VSCode that allow you to edit them for this type of thing, but they are very rare.

What you can do is **try to create your own extension** for your company, it's really easy, you can see how to start [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension), and see how to create content for your extension like commands [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/overview)